# Respond_to does not call the right format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-2

Rails 2.3.18

I have a `Answer` controller with an index function like this :

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { }
    format.all { redirect_to ... }
  end
end
```

I have a `anwers/index.js.erb` associated to this index action, for `:js` format.

I just enter URL `/answers/` in my browser to call the index function, and the result is surprising : this is the `index.js` displayed as a text.

Something is wrong with this, but I don't understand what !

I log the mime type on the index action, and this is "text/html", corresponding to :html format. Why `:js` format is called instead of `:all` format ?

Regards

Comment: You can't be using Ruby 2.3.18. Do you mean Rails 2.3.18? Also, what URL are you entering into the browser? You just said "I enter URL". The more details you can provide the better

Comment: Try using `format.html` instead of format.all

Answer (score 0):

Try using `format.html` and `format.js` without passing a block as shown below. I've never seen format.all used before.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

Comment: The documentation in Apidock use this :all format  : http://apidock.com/rails/Mime http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to#604-A-catch-all-format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{redirect_to ...}
    format.js {}
  end
end
```